# Add NOT NULL column with default value as empty string in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on Rails and trying to achieve this:

I want to add a string column which is NOT NULL and holds the default value ''.

Here is my migration:

```
add_column :campaigns, :from_name, :string, limit: 100, :null => false, :defualt => ''
```

This migration works fine but when I see table in pgAdmin (PostgresQL) I see columns created but no default value:

```
from_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
```

I tried same thing using pgAdmin and I could create

```
from_name character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
```

What is wrong here??

Comment: You have a typo in your migration, "`:defualt`". So unless that's a copy error I suggest that's your problem.

Comment: Oh God! I feel very stupid having spent 2 hrs on this :( thanks a lot @MikeCampbell

Comment: @MikeCampbell just wonder why it didn't give any error/warning?

Comment: @Pramodtech Rails ignores arbitrary named parameters that are passed to migrations.

Comment: heh, no worries, we've all done it. and yep, @tamizhgeek is right.

Comment: @MikeCampbell how come you put your (correct) solution in a comment instead of an answer? Just curious... I've noticed a lot of people doing this.

Comment: Good question! Don't know really, it was an answer so it should probably have been posted as an answer. Just felt it was so simple it didn't warrant more than a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you typed: **defualt** instead of **default**.

Try to fix that.